# How to parse ODBC connection string with special characters

Tags: c++, odbc

While trying to figure out how to parse ODBC connection string containing special characters(`[]{}(),;?`) I'd like to know if what I am trying to achieve is a valid requirement or not.
The [SQLDriverConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver15#comments) reads:

> A DSN or connection string value enclosed with braces ({}) containing
> any of the characters []{}(),;?*=!@ is passed intact to the driver.

To me, it means special characters(`[]{}(),;?`) are allowed including `curly braces` and `semicolon` in between (at least in values).

So, is it valid to expect PWD key(for example) look like this `PWD={a{b}};c};`?

And should its value be parsed to `a{b}};c`?

And if yes, can such a requirement be even easily achieved? Inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30338543/805896) my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class CSVState {
    UnquotedField,
    QuotedField
};

std::vector<std::string> readCSVRow(const std::string &row) {
    CSVState state = CSVState::UnquotedField;
    std::vector<std::string> fields {""};
    size_t i = 0; // index of the current field
    int depth = 0;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < row.size(); ++ii) {
        auto& c = row[ii];
        switch (state) {
            case CSVState::UnquotedField:
                switch (c) {
                    case ';': // end of field
                              fields.push_back(""); i++;
                              break;
                    case '{': state = CSVState::QuotedField;
                              depth++;
                              break;
                    default:  fields[i].push_back(c);
                              break; 
                }
                break;
            case CSVState::QuotedField:
                switch (c) {
                    case '{': //state = CSVState::QuotedQuote;
                              depth++;
                              fields[i].push_back(c);
                              break;
                    case '}': 
                              depth--;
                              if (depth == 0) {
                                state = CSVState::UnquotedField;
                              } else {
                                fields[i].push_back(c);
                              }
                              break;
                    default:  fields[i].push_back(c);
                              break; 
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "fields: " << fields.size() << std::endl;
    return fields;
}

/// Read CSV file, Excel dialect. Accept "quoted fields ""with quotes"""
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> readCSV(std::istream &in) {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> table;
    std::string row;
    std::getline(in, row);
    if (in.bad() || in.fail()) {
        std::cout << "bad\n";
        return {};
    }
    auto fields = readCSVRow(row);
    table.push_back(fields);
    for(auto& f : fields) {
        std::cout << "'" << f << "' ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return table;
}

int main() {
     auto res = readCSV(std::cin);
}
```

For input `{a{b}};c};` it will produce `'a{b}' 'c}' ''` while I think it should be modified to produce `a{b}};c}`.

Any clues how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph you mentioned refers to attributes, not strings. So for the string `{a{b}};c};` the attributes separated by semicolon are `{a{b}}`, `c}` and `''`.

> A DSN or connection string **value** enclosed with braces

The key word here is **value**, meaning attribute value in the string.

So any attribute value can be enclosed in braces to be passed as is, but not the entire string.

**Edit**: If you want to parse values in braces no matter what they contain you can simply check the depth when encountering a semicolon:

```
case ';': // end of field
    if (depth == 0) {
        fields.push_back(""); i++;
    } else {
        fields[i].push_back(c);
    }
    
    break;
```

This way `{a{b}};c};` will be parsed as `{a{b}};c}` and `''` because only the semicolon that is not in braces is used.

Comment: The point is, the first semicolon is meant to be part of the attribute value. In the end, one needs to extract the whole password as: `a{b}};c`

Comment: @rahman, I think I understand what you want. Please see my edit.